# How to upload a file via <input type:"file"> and send this file as data-binary in a curl?

Tags: javascript, rest, http, backend, node-red

First of all, im a beginner in  web services, API calls, HTTP requests and backend development, so maybe im saying stuff that doesnt make any sense, but I will try to explain in a way where everyone cna understand.

I have an audio file on my PC. I want to upload this audio using a HTML form and . After this file is uploaded I want to send this audio file (POST method) as a data-binary (cURL) to make a HTTP request to an API REST service (speech-to-text). Is there any way to do this?

Im currently using a Javascript flow editor called Node-RED. I have done the following:
[image]

The speech to text, language translator and NLU services are from IBM Cloud.

Could anyone please tell me how to get this done, or at least tell me which topics I need to study in order to get this done?

I really appreciate it if anyone could provide me a lead.

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Why do you want to move this out of Node-RED? You could just replace the file inject node with a HTTP-in/HTTP-Response pair.

Answer (score 0):

cURL support such calls, take a look at the `--data-binary` option in its man page or here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary

Quoting the same docs:

> (HTTP) This posts data exactly as specified with no extra processing whatsoever. If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a filename.